# Problem when using echo'd ++$value in javascript as part of a html5 audio player page

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html5-audio

I have been making myself a 'soundboard' that populates a custom HTML5 audio player for each mp3 file it finds in a directory. Now that side of it is all working exactly as I expected but my problems started when I have attempted to add a custom timer which uses javascript.

For each player, I was able to make custom controls and make the variables all marry up with things like

```
<audio id="player<?php echo $count1++;?>" src="audio/<?php echo rtrim($file, " "); ?>"></audio>
```

So using PHP echo a lot to repeat the players and controls but with new ids and as mentioned this is all functioning great but when I try and apply the same to a javascript snippet I'm using this is where my problems start as the ++ seems to be going a bit Pete Tong and is resulting in 2,4,6,8 or 3,6,9,12 when I was expecting 1,2,3,4

Here is the js code in question

```
// Get the audio element with id from variable
var count10 = "<?php echo $count10 ;?>";
var aud = document.getElementById("player" + count10);

    // Assign an ontimeupdate event to the audio element, and execute a function if the current playback position has changed
    aud.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};

    var count11 = "<?php echo $count11 ;?>";
    function myFunction() {
      // Display the current position of the audio in a p element with id from var
      document.getElementById("time" + count11).innerHTML = aud.currentTime;
    }
```

To be clear my issue is adding a timer which should appear under each play/stop button once you hit play, this currently only works for the 1st player instance in my pastebin code above.

I've spent 4-5 hours now on nothing but trying to solve this without having to ask on here and have got to the point Its no longer fun! Please help, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than keep a separate count to link the the item, you can use the foreach loop to give you the item index...

So when you do

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
```

you can use

```
foreach ($files as $id => $file) {
```

and then use

```
echo $id;
```

inside the loop to output the corresponding ID.