# Adding an increasing number into a php array (so i can later call it with a php echo)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

With this code

```
$files = scandir('audio');
$files = array_slice($files, 2);
$files = array_combine(range(1, count($files)), $files);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";
```

I am able to scan a dir and list its files in an array like so..

```
Array
(
    [1] => audio1.mp3
    [2] => audio2.mp3
    [3] => audio3.mp3
)
```

What I'd like to do is insert an increasing value number for each file it finds that I can later reference so the array becomes

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => audio1.mp3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => audio2.mp3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => audio3.mp3
        )
)
```

I haven't a clue where to start with this one so can't say what I've tried, any help appreciated.
PS: this is in a bid for me to solve the issue I'm having in this question [Problem when using echo'd ++$value in javascript as part of a html5 audio player page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193307/problem-when-using-echod-value-in-javascript-as-part-of-a-html5-audio-player) because if these values are in the array I won't have to increase them with ++ on the echo side.

Comment: From your original code, when you do `foreach ($files as $file) {`, you can use `foreach ($files as $id => $file) {` and then echo `$id` instead.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks, Add this as an answer to my other question (linked in op) and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($files as $key=>$f) {
    $files[$key] = array($key, $f);
}
```